# Alternative IDE to Develop Windows 8 Apps?

Tags: windows, windows-8, ide

I am interested in developing Windows 8 apps, but at the same time, the computer which I use to develop apps does not have an internet connection, and I want to keep it that way. The problem with this is that in order to develop for Windows 8, you need a free developer license, which cannot be acquired without an internet connection. Because of this, I would like an alternative IDE for developing Windows 8 apps. Does anybody know of any?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following hotfix (be sure to follow *all* of the instructions):

> [Hotfix enables developers to obtain a developer license for Windows Store without Internet connectivity](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2871280)

Comment: What exactly does this do? Based on the description, it sounds like it adds some new policies.

Comment: Okay. I installed the hotfix, made the group policy changes, and restarted, but my Visual Studio installation is still demanding a license. Previously I did have a license, but before installing the hotfix, I use PowerShell to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your computer to the internet, get your license (good for 30 days), disconnect your computer.

You could use Xamarin for Windows Phone 8 development but either way your are going to need an internet connection to publish your apps to the Windows Store and you'll need a developer license to do that.